# Copy values between two characters VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with copy value between same characters. Example below.

Let's say we have text like this:

```
"asd|qweeee|1123444|45555512345|swdq|" or 
"asdddd|qwwweeee|1123444|45555512345990|swdq|"
```

Is there any option to get value "1123444" from this string?

I want to copy values after 4 occurring character like "|".

in another words:

Copy value between 2nd "|" and 3rd "|".

Length of string is not the same.

I will be really thankful for any tips and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if you don't want to include empty segments when determining which to return.

That being the case, you can use a Regular Expression also:

```
Option Explicit
Function extrSegment(S As String, Optional Segment As Long = 3) As String
    Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "([^|]+)"
    .Global = True
    If .Test(S) = True Then
        extrSegment = .Execute(S)(Segment - 1).submatches(0)
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Note that there is an optional argument in the function for which segment to return, where `1` is the first segment.

You can also do this with a worksheet formula, especially if you have Excel 2013+ with the `FILTERXML` function:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s[text()!=''][3]")
```

That formula, also, will exclude empty segments from the determination of which is #3. However, if the segment has leading zero's, they will be dropped by the `FILTERXML` function.

Both methods result in:

[image]

**Edit:**

If you want to include empty nodes/segments in your count, then you can remove the 
text test from the `xPath` in the formula.

If you do that, `FILTERXML` will return an error for an empty node, so we need to test for that:

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(E1,"|","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s[3]"),"")
```

and the UDF can be simplified to just:

```
Function extrSegment(S As String, Optional Segment As Long = 4, Optional Delimiter As String = "|") As String
    extrSegment = Split(S, Delimiter)(Segment-1) 'array will be 0-based
End Function
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore `||`? What about `|||`? What would you expect for output from line 3 above?

Comment: For example we have text like this: "ED1|22222|123123123|FFFF|DDDD" and "ED1|22222||FFFF|DDDD"
And I want to give me "FFFF" from both, any tips? I am using your worksheet formula, it is better for me.

Comment: @Grzegorz See my Edit

Comment: I checked and now looks really great. Thank You Ron! Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Debug.Print Split(<your_string>, "|")(2)
```

In your example this would return "1123444". Note that `Split` will return an array with starting index `0`.

- 1st Element = `Split(<your string>, "|")(0)`
- 2nd Element = `Split(<your string>, "|")(1)`
- Etc..

If you got empty elements in the returned array, either loop them or make sure you "filter" them out beforehand, for example:

```
Debug.Print Split(Application.Trim(Replace(<your_string>, "|", " ")), " ")(2)
```

Comment: What if string is like this? "asd|||qweeee||1123444|45555512345|swdq|" There is blank values between "|". Macro ignoring blank values, I don't want to. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim s As String, items
s = "asd|qweeee|1123444|45555512345|swdq|"

items = Split(s, "|")
MsgBox items(2)
```

Comment: It's working for me. Perfect! That is what I was looking for. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: What if string is like this? 
"asd|||qweeee||1123444|45555512345|swdq|"
There is blank values between "|". Macro ignoring blank values, I don't want to. Any tips?

Comment: @Grzegorz: If you are not able to set a rule able to be understood by human people and your string will not look the same, only God can do that, not Excel VBA... For your last issue, try this: `Dim x As String` `x = "asd|||qweeee||1123444|45555512345|swdq|"` `Debug.Print Split(Replace(Replace(Trim(x), "|||", "|"), "||", "|"), "|")(2)`. I do not know if you can understand the code from here. I will try an answer...

Answer (score 0):

For your last request use the next code:

```
Sub testStringArr()
  Dim x As String
   x = "asd|||qweeee||1123444|45555512345|swdq|"
   Debug.Print Split(Replace(Replace(Trim(x), "|||", "|"), "||", "|"), "|")(2)
End Sub
```

But, if your string containing "| | |" comes from a function which could not find some elements and introduced spaces " " separated by "|", it is better to know where from this string is extracted and use it like it is, without the sausage formula. Just split it by "|" and return the appropriate number of array element according to your investigation about the string origine.